# How to use Symfony 1.4 image_tag helper to access photos under web folders

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I want to implement a 'who's online' in my Symfony 1. 4 app.I know , That in order to display a photo for example (in /web/images/photo.png), Symfony has this image_tag helper

```
<?php echo image_tag('photo.png') ?>
```

How to correctly display a photo, example nation flag to a corresponding user if the photos are in /web/images/flags?.I tried this in templates

```
 //templates
<ul>
<?php foreach($codes as $code): ?>
  <li>
    <?php echo image_tag("/images/flags/".strtolower($code->countrycode).".gif") ?> <?php echo $code->country ?> (<?php echo $code->count ?>)
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>


my_app
/app
/modules
/web
  /images
    /flags
```

But It will not display the corresponding photo(nation's flag).Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path without leading slash:

```
image_tag("flags/".strtolower($code->countrycode).".gif");
```